# Building a powerbank into a record player

Tags: batteries, powerbanks

My "portable" record player has a 5VDC 2A input via a barrel power jack and I want to use a normal powerbank to make it truely portable.

Can I just solder the 5V output of my powerbank to the 5V input of the barrel power jack via an on-off switch? The switch is so I can disconnect the powerbank when using the record player over the normal power cable.

I sketched something out in Fritzing with the MAX15 PCB representing the internals of the powerbank/record player.

I have never before worked with liion batteries and I am a bit scared of blowing something up.

[image: sketch of the setup in fritzing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can hardwire a power bank to a device. The risk you are running into is you will forget to turn off the switch to the power bank when you plug in the external power barrel jack into the record player. What I would suggest is that you wire the 5V output of the power bank to the same format DC barrel jack, so that you can simply plug it into the record player instead of hardwiring it.

Comment: It's been some time but I had a weird idea of putting a diode on the 5V wire between the barrel-jack and the switch? Wouln't that solve all my problems?

Comment: Yes, an inline diode on the 5V line from the power bank would prevent you from having to switch it off when you plug in the normal power cable. Choose a power diode.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't your power bank have a USB output?  Get any random USB cable capable of 2A. Lop off the B-end.  Measure out which wire is positive.  Wire the two power wires to that kind of barrel jack with correct polarity. Done.

Comment: Yes I already thought of that aswell, but the record player is inside of a small suitcase so it would look cooler if the powerbank was integrated.